# Trying to find out previous Year Opportunity Count in power Bi?

Tags: dax

I'm trying to compare current year count with previous year count. I'm using opportunity close date as slicer. however I'm able to get current year count, but when I try to calculate previous year count, it is coming bank. what is suspect is that the record set selected gets filtered based on Current year and when I further try to filter it based on previous year value it is not finding any record hence giving blank value. please suggest how to fix this issue.